# Reorder fields in open cart product form

Tags: field, opencart, vqmod

This .xml file and vqmod created my new custom post field in the products post type of my openchart.

```
<modification>
    <id>Custom Field - unit_price</id>
    <version>1</version>
    <vqmver>1.0.8</vqmver>
    <author>Jonathan de Jong - tigerton.se</author>
    
    <file name="admin/language/english/catalog/product.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                $_['entry_model']            = 'Model:';
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                $_['entry_unit_price']         = 'unit_price:';
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file name="admin/model/catalog/product.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($data['model']) . "', sku = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sku']) . "', upc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['upc']) . "', location = '" . $this->db->escape($data['location']) . "', quantity = '" . (int)$data['quantity'] . "', minimum = '" . (int)$data['minimum'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$data['subtract'] . "', stock_status_id = '" . (int)$data['stock_status_id'] . "', date_available = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_available']) . "', manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['manufacturer_id'] . "', shipping = '" . (int)$data['shipping'] . "', price = '" . (float)$data['price'] . "', points = '" . (int)$data['points'] . "', weight = '" . (float)$data['weight'] . "', weight_class_id = '" . (int)$data['weight_class_id'] . "', length = '" . (float)$data['length'] . "', width = '" . (float)$data['width'] . "', height = '" . (float)$data['height'] . "', length_class_id = '" . (int)$data['length_class_id'] . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', tax_class_id = '" . $this->db->escape($data['tax_class_id']) . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$data['sort_order'] . "', date_added = NOW()");
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($data['model']) . "', sku = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sku']) . "', upc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['upc']) . "', location = '" . $this->db->escape($data['location']) . "', quantity = '" . (int)$data['quantity'] . "', minimum = '" . (int)$data['minimum'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$data['subtract'] . "', stock_status_id = '" . (int)$data['stock_status_id'] . "', date_available = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_available']) . "', manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['manufacturer_id'] . "', shipping = '" . (int)$data['shipping'] . "', price = '" . (float)$data['price'] . "', points = '" . (int)$data['points'] . "', weight = '" . (float)$data['weight'] . "', weight_class_id = '" . (int)$data['weight_class_id'] . "', length = '" . (float)$data['length'] . "', width = '" . (float)$data['width'] . "', height = '" . (float)$data['height'] . "', length_class_id = '" . (int)$data['length_class_id'] . "', unit_price = '" . $this->db->escape($data['unit_price']) . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', tax_class_id = '" . $this->db->escape($data['tax_class_id']) . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$data['sort_order'] . "', date_added = NOW()");

            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
                $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($data['model']) . "', sku = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sku']) . "', upc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['upc']) . "', location = '" . $this->db->escape($data['location']) . "', quantity = '" . (int)$data['quantity'] . "', minimum = '" . (int)$data['minimum'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$data['subtract'] . "', stock_status_id = '" . (int)$data['stock_status_id'] . "', date_available = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_available']) . "', manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['manufacturer_id'] . "', shipping = '" . (int)$data['shipping'] . "', price = '" . (float)$data['price'] . "', points = '" . (int)$data['points'] . "', weight = '" . (float)$data['weight'] . "', weight_class_id = '" . (int)$data['weight_class_id'] . "', length = '" . (float)$data['length'] . "', width = '" . (float)$data['width'] . "', height = '" . (float)$data['height'] . "', length_class_id = '" . (int)$data['length_class_id'] . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', tax_class_id = '" . $this->db->escape($data['tax_class_id']) . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$data['sort_order'] . "', date_modified = NOW() WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($data['model']) . "', sku = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sku']) . "', upc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['upc']) . "', location = '" . $this->db->escape($data['location']) . "', quantity = '" . (int)$data['quantity'] . "', minimum = '" . (int)$data['minimum'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$data['subtract'] . "', stock_status_id = '" . (int)$data['stock_status_id'] . "', date_available = '" . $this->db->escape($data['date_available']) . "', manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['manufacturer_id'] . "', shipping = '" . (int)$data['shipping'] . "', price = '" . (float)$data['price'] . "', points = '" . (int)$data['points'] . "', weight = '" . (float)$data['weight'] . "', weight_class_id = '" . (int)$data['weight_class_id'] . "', length = '" . (float)$data['length'] . "', width = '" . (float)$data['width'] . "', height = '" . (float)$data['height'] . "', length_class_id = '" . (int)$data['length_class_id'] . "', unit_price = '" . $this->db->escape($data['unit_price']) . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', tax_class_id = '" . $this->db->escape($data['tax_class_id']) . "', sort_order = '" . (int)$data['sort_order'] . "', date_modified = NOW() WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file name="admin/controller/catalog/product.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                $this->data['entry_model'] = $this->language->get('entry_model');
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                $this->data['entry_unit_price'] = $this->language->get('entry_unit_price');
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search position="before"><![CDATA[
                if (isset($this->request->post['sku'])) {
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                if (isset($this->request->post['unit_price'])) {
                    $this->data['unit_price'] = $this->request->post['unit_price'];
                } elseif (!empty($product_info)) {
                    $this->data['unit_price'] = $product_info['unit_price'];
                } else {
                    $this->data['unit_price'] = '';
                }
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file name="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="after" offset="10"><![CDATA[
            <td><?php echo $entry_weight_class; ?></td>
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $entry_unit_price; ?></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="unit_price" value="<?php echo $unit_price; ?>" /></td>
              </td>
            </tr>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file name="catalog/controller/product/product.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            $this->data['text_model'] = $this->language->get('text_model');
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            $this->data['text_unit_price'] = $this->language->get('text_unit_price');
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file name="catalog/language/english/product/product.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                $_['tab_related']       = 'Related Products'; 
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                $_['text_unit_price']         = 'unit_price:';
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file name="catalog/language/english/product/product.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                $_['tab_related']       = 'Relaterade produkter'; 
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                $_['text_unit_price']         = 'unit_price:';
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file name="catalog/controller/product/product.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
                $this->data['manufacturer'] = $product_info['manufacturer'];
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
                $this->data['unit_price'] = $product_info['unit_price'];
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

which works great!

the thing is that it's one of the last ones now

[image]

Is there a way I can make it the next field to 'price' field?

if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within this section:

```xml
<file name="admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.tpl">
    <operation>
        <search position="after" offset="10"><![CDATA[
        <td><?php echo $entry_weight_class; ?></td>
        ]]></search>
        <add><![CDATA[
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $entry_unit_price; ?></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="unit_price" value="<?php echo $unit_price; ?>" /></td>
          </td> <!-- <- ALSO REMOVE THAT LINE FROM YOUR XML FILE... -->
        </tr>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

change the `<search>` part to:

```xml
<search position="after" offset="3"><![CDATA[<td><?php echo $entry_price; ?></td>]]></search>
```

Play with the offset - it means how many lines after the one that is found the `add` part will be added. I guess it should be 3, but maybe You would have to adjust it a little (maybe only to 2).